# trying to get table recoreds to datagrid view one by one

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server

this is my code but this is giving last record only. but i need all records one by one

```
string query = "select * from tbl_users;";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();

        for (int x = 0; x <= total; x++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells["colNic"].Value = reader["NIC"].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells["colName"].Value = reader["name"].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells["colAge"].Value = reader["age"].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells["colCity"].Value = reader["city"].ToString();
            }

        }
        con.Close();
```

Comment: Where does `total` come from? Shouldn't that be derived from `reader` instead of hard-coded in some variable somewhere? And are you sure you're getting the "last" row? How do you know? Your query doesn't have an `order by` so you could literally be getting *any* single row.

Answer (score 2):

What i undestand from the above is that you actually want to add each record in datagridview as row, so the following should be the code for that:

```
string query = "select * from tbl_users;";
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, con);
con.Open();
SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    int x = dataGridView1.Rows.Add(); // add new row for each db row in grid
                                      // and use index returned by it
    DataGridViewRow currentRow = dataGridView1.Rows[x];

    currentRow.Cells["colNic"].Value = reader["NIC"].ToString();
    currentRow.Cells["colName"].Value = reader["name"].ToString();
    currentRow.Cells["colAge"].Value = reader["age"].ToString();
    currentRow .Cells["colCity"].Value = reader["city"].ToString();

}
```

`dataGridView1.Rows.Add()` will return the index back for the newly created row, so you should be using that, you actually do not need that `for` loop, just iterate all the returned row using `while` and keep adding row in grid one by one.

Another suggestion here is that do not use `*` when selecting records from the table if you only need specific columns, always specify the columns that you need in the query like:

```
SELECT NIC,name,age,city FROM tbl_users
```

Hope it helps.